# Not able to import EntityState Added

Tags: breeze

I'm having an issue with importing cached data.  I have a very simple page right now to use as a proof of concept.  There is a single table in the back end.  I have all CRUD functionality working.  When the user makes a change to the local data, I update a record in local storage.

`var bundle = em.exportEntities(em.getChanges());
window.localStorage.setItem("waterLevelChanges", bundle);`

after the page is loaded I import the entities

```
var bundle = window.localStorage.getItem("waterLevelChanges");
        if (bundle)
            em.importEntities(bundle);
```

This works perfectly if I'm editing an existing record.  However, any records that I have added, but not saved to the database won't populate.  In the bundle they have an EntityState of "Added".  I read that there is an issue if you don't use the temp keys, but I'm letting Breeze use the temp keys and manage them as it likes.  I have verified the data is stored in the local cache by looking in the developer tools.  I can also see it in the bundle when I debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our tests show that your stated scenario should work fine.

See this [DocCode:export/importTests.js test](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/tests/exportImportTests.js#L100) where a new `Order` is exported, saved to browser storage, and reimported; it's "Added" state is confirmed. The `Order` type has server-generated, temporary keys.

I think you'll have to create a repro of your failing scenario to convince me that it doesn't work. Perhaps you might start by forking [**this Todos plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/xgR82qCkDlzkqy06ENXR?p=info) and modifying it to make your point; a `TodoItem` also has has server-generated, temporary keys.

Comment: Thanks for the link to your test.  Yes, after looking into the em.getEntitites I can see that the added items are in there.  So it appears that my issue is I'm missing a link between them and my observable array.  Would you suggest that I loop through the entities after import and I would push any items with an EntityState of Added  into the observable array?

Comment: Can't answer properly until I see your code for the observable array. My instinct is that it has nothing to do with Added. When you import, of course any entities that weren't in the importing em's cache before will be new JavaScript objects that are not in any array. Old Added entities will still be there even if their dopplegangers have been imported and given new temp keys. Is that a clue?